# Policy creation based on folder path and json inside folder

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have paths in terraform for which I want to prepare a mapping list based on folder -

So say -

- Security

  - File1
- Infrastructuer

  - File2

```
locals {
paths = {
    for ou in var.core_ous : ou => "${path.module}/policies/${lower(ou)}"
  }

  policies = { 
    for f in setproduct(var.core_ous,local.paths) : "${f[0]}/${f[1]}" => {
      ou = f[0]
      file = fileset(lookup(f[1],f[0],""),"*.json") 
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error as when I try to create list of paths based on folder as -

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on modules/organizations/locals.tf line 21, in locals:
│   21:     for f in setproduct(var.core_ous,local.paths) : "${f[0]}/${f[1]}" => {
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.paths is object with 2 attributes
│
│ Invalid value for "sets" parameter: a set or a list is required.
```

I inspected the output of `paths` and it is coming as -

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + files = {
      + Infrastructure = "modules/organizations/policies/infrastructure"
      + Security       = "modules/organizations/policies/security"
    }
```

how can I loop through based on only on var.core_ous to build a map like based on json files -

- Security

  - filepath 1
  - filepath 2
- Infrastructure

  - filepath 3
  - filepath 4

and then loop through this to apply it on policy as -

```
policies = { 
    for f in setproduct(var.core_ous,local.paths) : "${f[0]}/${f[1]}" => {
      ou = f[0]
      file = fileset(lookup(f[1],f[0],""),"*.json") 
    }
  }
```

How can we achieve this ?

Comment: What is `var.core_ous`?

Comment: @Marcin They are just list of string core_ous = ["Security","Infrastructure"] which are same as the folders which I am trying to bring up the policies json files to be read from .